# How to run pandoc with a keybinding in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have been trying to configure a keybinding to run pandoc when in a markdown file, but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have in my current `vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <C-s> :w <CR> :!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf <CR>
```

So, when I press ctrl+s it *should* save then run pandoc, but it doesn't. Instead, nothing happens.

I've tried running echo, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Linux? In Unix `Ctrl-S` is used for terminal control flow and should not be used for mappings.

Comment: @phd small correction: `Ctrl-s`

Comment: @weirdsmiley Really? I see only uppercase Control characters in [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html#normal-index).

Comment: @phd Yes, I now know that. I‘ve answered my own question with a fix that worked. Pretty dumb mistake haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god... I'll post the answer for anyone who has the same problem, but it's kind of embarrassing.

The only thing that needed to be fixed was the keybinding LOL. I changed it from ctrl+s to F1 and it worked fine.

Edit: Ok... it's actually a bit weirder than I thought. I seems to only work sometimes. I can run it directly after I open the file, but if I edit something then I need to move around a bit. Super strange.